# Is the HP ProCurve 1800-24G Switch fanless or not?

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, physical-environment

Does the HP ProCurve 1800-24G Switch have a fan or not?

[The specs](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06b/12136296-12136298-12136298-12136298-12627666-12627718-77904485.html?dnr=1) say that it does not have a fan, and so do many references I can see on the web.  However, a person who is offering to sell me a used one is insisting that it does have a fan, although it is relatively quiet.

Are there different versions?  Could it actually be a fake?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of them do have a fan. I have one sitting here on my desk that has the fan and it's the J9028A version.

Comment: I ended up getting a brand new 1810G-24 in the end, as I could be sure that it was silent.

Answer (score 4):

No, It's completely fanless. Hence the "Silent" in "HP ProCurve HP ProCurve 1800-24G Silent Gigabit Network Switch".

Comment: The seller insists the one he has has a fan.  Weird.

Comment: To add to the above, you have two variations, J9028A or J9028B. Both are 0db and fanless. I have read somewhere that it does give a very small buzzing noise (likely to be dust though).

Comment: @ColdT: It has been confirmed that not all of them are fanless.  It's pretty silly that HP did not give different model numbers to the different revisions.